# Не могу разобраться, как управлять "фоном иконок"

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, позиционирование

**Вот картинка, где показано, как должен выглядеть фон иконок при :hover**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А вот, как у меня вышло. (На границу не обращайте внимание, выделил, чтобы видеть родительский-блок)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:**

- *При :hover этот блок(фон) отодвигает другие блоки в стороны.*
- *Ещё фон должен быть "по центре логотипа" или логотип должен быть "по центре фона" (Как на первой картинке).*

***Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Буду признателен ;)***

```css
.md_khalil_uddin__img {
  background-image: url(img/Md.\ Khalil\ Uddin.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 265px;
  height: 253px;
}

.rubel_miah__img {
  background-image: url(img/Rubel\ Miah.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 266px;
  height: 253px;
}

.shamim_mia__img {
  background-image: url(img/Shamim\ Mia.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 266px;
  height: 253px;
}

.john_doe__img {
  background-image: url(img/John\ Doe.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 266px;
  height: 253px;
}

.user__hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.user__hover:hover {
  background: url(img/opacity_rectangle.png);
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.team__social_flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 266px;
  height: 253px;
}

.team__social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 116px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 195px auto auto auto;
  /* padding-top: 7px; */
  /* padding-bottom: 8px; */
}

.team__social_logo {}

.team__social_logo:hover {
  background: #C0301C;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="md_khalil_uddin__container">
  <div class="md_khalil_uddin__img">
    <div class="user__hover">
      <div class="team__social_flex">
        <div class="team__social">

          <div class="team__social_logo">
            <img src="img/facebook_logo.png" alt="facebook_logo">
          </div>

          <div class="team__social_logo">
            <img src="img/twitter_logo.png" alt="twitter_logo">
          </div>

          <div class="team__social_logo">
            <img src="img/google_plus_logo.png" alt="google_plus_logo">
          </div>

          <div class="team__social_logo">
            <img src="img/linkedin_logo.png" alt="linkedin_logo">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="figc1">Md. Khalil Uddin</div>
  <div class="figc2">Head of Ideas</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кусок кода вёрстки покажите и заданные стили

Comment: Создаёте список, в него кладёте 4 `li` и задаёте им размер, а в эти `li` кладёте логотипы и центруете их. При наведение на иконку, а по факту на `li` , просто меняете цвет этого `li`

Comment: Arsen, спасибо) Забыл код добавить в вопрос) Уже добавил)

Comment: @h , Спасибо огромное) Помогло) Осталось только по вертикали выровнять ;)